# How to add a list to a View Model MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, viewmodel

I'm using MVC 3 with View Model, in my case I have a View Model that should display a list of items and also a form for inserting some input.

I have problem in my View because I'm not able to associate the Form for inserting the data with the view model, could you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using TestGuestBook.Models;

namespace TestGuestBook.ViewModel
{
    public class ListAddCommentsViewModel
    {
        public int CommentId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Nominative { get; set; }

        [Email]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Content { get; set; }

        public List<Comment> CommentItems { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View

```
@model IEnumerable<TestGuestBook.ViewModel.ListAddCommentsViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>ListAddCommentsViewModel</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CommentId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CommentId)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CommentId)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nominative)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nominative)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nominative)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Content)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Content)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Content)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            CommentId
        </th>
        <th>
            Nominative
        </th>
        <th>
            Email
        </th>
        <th>
            Content
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CommentId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nominative)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Content)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: In your view you have a form to create a new comment and a table to show all the comments, do you? Could you put your controller code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You dont need to pass a `Collection` to your View. Only one object of the ViewModel is enough. Your `ViewModel` already have property to holde the collection (List of `Comments`)

So in your `GET` Action, return only one instance of this viewModel to the View

```
public ActionResult GetComments(int postId)
{
  var viewModel=new ListAddCommentsViewModel();
  viewModel.CommentItems =db.GetComments(postId);
  return View(viewModel);
}
```

and now in your View, Let it bind to a single instance of `ListAddCommentsViewModel`

```
@model TestGuestBook.ViewModel.ListAddCommentsViewModel
```

And Inside your view, to Show your List of comments, use the Collection type property (`Model.CommentItems`)  in your `ViewModel`

```
@foreach (var item in Model.CommentItems) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CommentId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nominative)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Content)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {  @id=item.PrimaryKey  }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new {  @id=item.PrimaryKey  }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { @id=item.PrimaryKey  })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: So, if i want to add a new coment how should i show the html here

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution, I had checked almost all information and this is the one working!! Thanks

```
    public  ActionResult UploadFile(UploadFileViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var file = model.File;
            var parsedContentDisposition =
            ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition);
            var filename = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath,
                "Uploads", parsedContentDisposition.FileName.Trim('"'));
            file.SaveAsAsync(filename);
        }

        return View();
    }
```